# join two subqueries syntax error using mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am using the following code in sql and it gives me syntax error. Can anyone help me find out why? Thanks!

```
(
select accepter_id, count(*) as accept_cnt
from request_accepted
group by accepter_id) a
left join
(
select requester_id, count(*) as request_cnt
from request_accepted
group by requester_id) b
on a.accepter_id = b.requester_id
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit hard without the definition for request_accepted, but here is my trial for you:

```
select a.accepter_id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM request_accepted ac WHERE ac.accepter_id = a.accepter_id) AS accept_cnt, 
    b.requester_id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM request_accepted bc WHERE bc.requester_id = b.requester_id) AS request_cnt
from request_accepted a
left join request_accepted b
on a.accepter_id = b.requester_id
GROUP BY a.accepter_id, b.requester_id
```